# Calculate following definite integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The task is to calculate the following integral:

$$\int_{1/3}^{3}{\frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x^{2}-x+1}dx}$$

However the answer me currently getting seems to be too large and odd, any ideas of more efficient solution?
P.S I was using universal substitution for rational trigonometric equations

Comment: I would integrate by parts, differentiating the arctangent, hope to end up with a rational function.

Comment: @gt6989b Tried that, however the amount of calculations seems rather enormous, comparing with other problems given..